# ImageView and VideoView on same activity

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-videoview

I'm trying to display a captured image on my MainActivity. The problem is it says that onActivityResult is already defined. My first onActivityResult is for the VideoView. Now I have to put a new onActivityResult for my image. How do I make this possible? Do I only have to have one onActivityResult? Do I have to put the second onActivityResult to the first onActivityResult?

Here's my code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Button buttonPlay;
    Button buttonFullScreen;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;
    MediaController mediacontroller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        resultvideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent(View v) {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
            resultvideo.pause();

        }
        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        {
            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediacontroller.show();
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
                    resultvideo.start();
                }
            });
        }

        buttonFullScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFullScreen);
        {
            buttonFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_URI", videoUri.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not regarding your issue, but, you should not place view initializations in onActivityResoult. Place it in an init function, which you can put in onCreate, this is just an example. Also, check the ButterKnife library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create two view ImageView for Image and VideoView for Video and use this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    //Hide video view
                    videoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                //bring your video stuff here
                videoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only a single `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` for your Activity class

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode){
                case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    }
                    break;
                case REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                    //bring your video stuff here
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Your onActivityResult should look like the above code. Every function can be declared with a the same types and order of parameters only once in a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two function with the same signature.

You have to have a single onActivityResult, and in the if statement, you have to handle the resoult.

Example

```
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){    
      if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ) {
           ...    
      }   
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE ) {
           ...  
      } 
}
```